# Why do we squint?

Tags: vision

Recently, I was having an eye exam and admitted to squinting my eyes to sharpen blurred edges. Later, while waiting for the dilation to set in, my brother (a would-be pharmacist fresh off an anatomy course) was telling me about how vision works.

As a non-scientist, here's as much as I gathered:

- The pupil allows light into our eyes.
- The lens bends and shifts to focus that light against our retina.
- The retina translates this light-information into signals via the optic nerve.
- Something about brains, and then *sight!*

So, my question is, if the lens being bent and shifted inside of our eye by muscles is how our eyes focus, **why do those of us with poor vision squint?** Surely it can't be that by narrowing my field of vision I'm consciously bending my lens.

Comment: When I was younger (before I got glasses), I sometimes used to pinch four fingers together to make a tiny square hole and look through it. Same principle as squinting; you decrease the aperture size.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's a bit physics and biology,

It works, all right. In fact, the word "**myopia**" (near-sightedness) comes from the Greek words myein (shut) and ops (eye). When you squint, it's like reducing the aperture of a camera lens: You reduce the diameter of your visual lens. This gives you a longer depth of focus.

Shortly you can say, **Yes** by squinting your eyes you actually bends the eye lens with the help of Ciliary Muscles present in your eyes which reduce it's focal length and helps you to see with a better vision